# Accelerometer and gyrometer readings relative to device orientation

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

I am working with the accelerometer and gyrometer readings on a mobile device and I want to get the readings relative to the device orientation.

For what I will call orientation A the device is flat on a table in portrait mode and I tap on the left (long) side of
the device there will be certain accelerometer and gyrometer readings.
Then I raise the device vertically, still in portrait mode but facing me  and I tap on the left side of the device, call this
orientation B.

I want to compare the motion from orientations A to the motion from orientation B. Is there a matrix M such that:

```
orientation B * M = orientation A
```

and could M be applied to accelerometer and gyrometer readings at orientation B so that they appear as if there were done when the device was in orientation A? I am looking for something that works
for any device orientation.

Is there something obvious I am missing or interesting mathematics to do this?

thanks in advance,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out:

```
q1 is the Android rotation vector (quaternion) at orientation A
q2 is the quaternion at orientation B
a2 is a 3-tuple describing the acceleration at orientation B

a2's acceleration with respect to the q1 coordinate system is:
   q1.rotate( q2.inverse.rotate( a2 ) )
```

This is using the Python quaternion library.